# How to have space and special character in data bind-ed xml?

Tags: android, xml, data-binding, android-databinding

```
  android:text="@{'\u2022' +item.title}"
```

I'm using data binding and should space +  bullet  + space + title
put when I add space it breaks

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do what you suggest in the question:

```
android:text="@{`\u0020\u2022\u0020` + item.title}"
```

But it is better to use string formatting:

```
<string name="bullet"> \u2022 %1$s</string>
```

and use it like this:

```
android:text="@{@string/bullet(item.title)}"
```

I'm pretty sure that `\u0020` is just a normal space, so I just used a normal space in the string resource.

Answer (score 0):

I want to answer my question

```
android:text="@{(@string/space).concat(@string/bullet).concat(@string/space).concat(item.title)}"


<string name="space">\u0020</string>
<string name="bullet">\u2022</string>
```